# How to add a new node at a specific index in doubly linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

How to add a new node at a specific index in doubly linked list. I wrote a function that is meant to add a new node at a specific index, but after i tested my function in the main program i got an infinite loop.

```
dlistint_t *insert_dnodeint_at_index(dlistint_t **h, unsigned int idx, int n)
{
        dlistint_t *temp;
        dlistint_t *new_node;
        unsigned int count;

        temp = *h;
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(dlistint_t));
        if (new_node == NULL)
                return (NULL);
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->n = n;
        if (idx == 0)
        {
                *h = new_node;
                return (new_node);
        }
        else
        {
                count = 0;
                while (temp != NULL && count != idx - 1)
                {
                        temp = temp->next;
                        count++;
                }
                if (count != idx - 1)
                {
                        return (NULL);
                }
                temp->next = new_node;
                new_node->next = temp;
                new_node->prev = temp;
                return (new_node);
        }
}
```

Comment: Split up your logic into small functions.

Comment: If you want to insert at (e.g.) index 5, do you want to insert the new node before or after the _existing_ node at index 5? Also, what do you want to do if you have only 2 nodes already in the list? Do you want to append to the end or drop the new node and return `NULL`?

Comment: Assuming the index given by the user is greater than the length of the linked list, the code should return the original length of the linked list

Comment: Okay, that answers my 2nd question. For a match to an existing node, do you want to insert before or after it?

Comment: At index of 5 the new node should displace the the original node while the old node will adjust to the sixth index

Comment: The only logic i can split here is the function that creates the new node